# What is this Diode for?

Tags: diodes, opto-isolator, protection, isolation

This part of a schematic from the I/O board in the link below shows a 1N4148 diode in parallel with an optocoupler's input circuitry.
What is this diode for?

https://startingelectronics.org/projects/small-open-source-PLC/PLC-components/

I'm thinking of 3 things.

1. A diode that prevents negative voltages from damaging the optocoupler.
2. A diode that protects the optocoupler's input from overvoltages.
3. A flyback diode. (Very unlikely for semicons right?)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is ... #1. It protects the LED in the optoisolator from negative voltages that could applied by the user. From the datasheet:

[image]

The Zener diode will, of course, conduct as a diode in the forward direction if a negative voltage is applied, leaving the remainder of the input voltage across the LED until it starts to break down in reverse.

Comment: Thank you very much Spehro Pefhany!

Answer (score 1):

You can also connect a red LED instead of the diode, in the same direction as that of diode. It will give the user a quick visual indication also that he has connected something in reverse.

The forward voltage of red LED is about 2 V.  And this will not harm the optocoupler. The heat generated due to the reverse leakage current and the lower forward vorlage drop will not harm the optocoupler.

Comment: That is a great idea. Thanks!